# How to have seperators between tabs in new Firefox?

Tags: firefox, browser, firefox-extensions

The new Firefox update (June 2021) is nice and minimalistic - however, I really dislike how difficult it is to make out where one tab starts and ends as there is no divider between the tabs:

[image]

I can't find any plugin or theme that will fix this for me. It's really hurting my productivity since I keep clicking the wrong tab. Is there something I can install to get the lines between tabs again?

Comment: hmmm… it looks just like the rest of Windows now ;))

Comment: The design movement that's resulted in the elimination of visual delimiters has had the unintended consequence of excluding those with imperfect vision or visual cognition. This is often referred to as "minimalism," "decluttering," and reducing UI busyness.

Inclusive design would consider the wide range of human visual abilities, rather than just the near-perfect.  In reality, designer regard for lower visual ability really only kicks in when Section 508 compliance is considered: those with either very low, or no, visual ability.

Answer (score 1):

Using [userChrome.css](https://www.howtogeek.com/334716/how-to-customize-firefoxs-user-interface-with-userchrome.css/), you can customize many aspects of Firefox. In the example below, inactive, default, tabs have a gradient white to gray; the tab over which the cursor *hovers* is a gradient from dark gray to white; and the *active tab* uses a horizontal colored gradient. This makes the distinction amongst tabs much more clear to me.

[image: Horizontal tab separation]

- Enable CSS: in *about:config*, set `toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets` to `true`.
- Open your Firefox profile.

  - Linux, *Home.mozilla\firefox\xxxxxxxx.default*
  - Windows, *C:\Users<username>\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\xxxxxxxx.default*
  - Mac OS, *Users//Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/xxxxxxxx.default*
- If there is no folder *Chrome*, create it.
- If there is no file *userChrome.css* in that folder, create it as a text document, i.e. with Kate, Notepad++, or other text editor.
- Copy and paste text below and save the file. (If you're editing an existing *userChrome.css* and the `@namespace` line exists, there's no need to duplicate it.)
- Close and restart Firefox to see the new tab style.

  ```
  @namespace url("http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul");

  /* Tab: default colors */
  #tabbrowser-tabs .tabbrowser-tab:not([selected]) .tab-content { background: linear-gradient(to right,#FFFFFF,#BBBBBB) !important; }
  /* Tab: selected colors */
  #tabbrowser-tabs .tabbrowser-tab[selected] .tab-content { background: linear-gradient(to right,#AAFFAA,#FFAAFF) !important; }
  /* Tab: hovered colors */
  #tabbrowser-tabs .tabbrowser-tab:hover:not([selected]) .tab-content { background: linear-gradient(to right,#808080,#FFFFFF) !important; }
  ```

Feel free to modify the appearance to your taste.